# Complex Shape Not Correctly Unwrapping

Tags: animation, mesh, materials, uv, objects

I am trying to make a render of a Japanese cookie box. In order to animate it, the top has to open. I built another object that represents the top, and traced the outline of the image to make the new shape. I am happy with the shape of the actual object. However, when I go to unwrap it the shape seems to change in the UV editor.

Here is an example image:

[image]

The box with the added top object hidden:

[image]

Anyone know what to do? Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Blender file: [image]

Comment: Hi. Could you pack the textures into your blend file and re-upload the file? 
I guess I know where the Problem is, but it would be easier to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier is to unwrap with '*project from view with bounds*' :
That gives you a flat projection of your 3D model into the UV map part. This projection depends on the 3D view itself, so you may want to align your model correctly (using <kbd>NumPad4</kbd> and <kbd>NumPad6</kbd>, for instance). Once done, you may have to adjust (grab and scale) your UV map a bit to fit your image.

[image]

Note : I took the wrong image from your screen captures, that why you still see the UVs from this image in the gif above even when the unwrap is done.